# select2 with parsley validation

Tags: jquery-select2, parsley.js

I've been searching through out the net but I can't find a way to validate select2 using parsley, the one discussed here doesn't seem to work [Select2 validate and force user to select ast least X items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635129/select2-validate-and-force-user-to-select-ast-least-x-items), this is very frustrating as i need the user to select at least 1 from the options. Can anyone provide me any work around?

Help appreciated!

Thank you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several reasons your custom validator might not work.

(1) Make sure you are using the correct instructions for the version of parsley.js you are using. I believe the attributes were not prefixed with "data-" for the 1.x versions, but are for the 2.x versions.

(2) The code shown in the stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535741/859640) to which you link must come before you include parsley.js. The code should be different if it comes after you include parsley.js.

Here is what the code should look like if it comes after you include parsley.js:

```
window.ParsleyValidator
    .addValidator('minSelect', function(value, requirement) {
        return value.split(',').length >= parseInt(requirement, 10);
    }, 32)
    .addMessage('en', 'minSelect', 'You must select at least %s.');
```

(3) It appears that parsley does not validate hidden input elements. So if you are backing your Select2 control with a hidden input (as opposed to a `<select>` element), change it to an `<input type="text">` element. It will still work with Select2, but parsley will validate it.

```
<input type="text" id="select" name="x" value=""
    data-parsley-minSelect="2"
    data-parsley-validate-if-empty="true" />
```

(4) It appears that by default parsley won't apply your custom validator when the value of the element is empty unless you include the `data-parsley-if-empty` attribute.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ku4o0m0u/5/)

Comment: This is awesome! just tweak a little to allow a minimum of 1. Thank you man, you save my day!!!

Comment: saved my day too :) You get +1

Answer (score 4):

I fixed my case just with **CSS**:

```
.sel2 .parsley-errors-list.filled {
margin-top: 42px;
margin-bottom: -60px;
}

.sel2 .parsley-errors-list:not(.filled) {
display: none;
}

.sel2 .parsley-errors-list.filled + span.select2 {
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.sel2 .parsley-errors-list.filled + span.select2 span.select2-selection--single {
    background: #FAEDEC !important;
    border: 1px solid #E85445;
}
```

and my select element:

```
<div class="sel2">
     <select id="select-country" class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1" required>
      ...
     </select>
</div>
```

and assign select2:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".select2_single").select2({
            placeholder: "Select from the list",
            allowClear: true
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

validate css

```
.select2-hidden-accessible.parsley-error ~ ul ~ .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
     border-color: #f34943 !important;
}

.select2-hidden-accessible.parsley-success ~ ul ~ .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
     border-color: #31ce77 !important;
}
```